# Execute a SQL Server stored procedure from a DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, stored-procedures, dll

I want to execute a SQL Server stored procedure using C#. This is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DBCon;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public class LoginDAl
    {
        public static DataSet  login_vald()
        {
            DBConnect myConnection = new DBConnect();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("ph.validate_app_user", myConnection.connection);
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        }

}
```

This is a dummy project for practice. Are DLLs the standard for DALs? This is a desktop application.
This a part of the DAL.

The error is

> login_vald()- not all code paths return a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is quite clear:

> login_vald()- not all code paths return a value

...means that your function is missing a `return` statement with an object of type `DataSet` something like:

```
public static DataSet  login_vald()
        {
            DBConnect myConnection = new DBConnect();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("ph.validate_app_user", myConnection.connection);
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

            return ds;   //this is missing
        }
```

Comment: In general it is always a good idea to have a data access layer. If you're unsure of how to call stored procedures take a look [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet). For anything else please be more specific about what is unclear to you.

Answer (score 0):

1. execute procedure (**something like da.Fill(ds);**)
2. **return dataset** (return ds;)

You have to look up for execute procedure command
[example](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/106200)

Comment: and seems absolutely improbable that a `validate_app_user` stored procedure could do anything without some kind of parameters (eg. username, password ???)

Comment: I will be putting those in my BO layer

Comment: What is the purpose of login_vald method? To validate if a user is registered/authorized?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a return statement, you also need to fill the DataSet with records

```
        public static DataSet  login_vald()
        {
            DBConnect myConnection = new DBConnect();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("ph.validate_app_user", myConnection.connection);
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(ds); //missing argument from SqlDataAdapter this will fill the ds

           return ds; //return filled DataSet
        }
```